# Cordova failed to fetch android

Tags: android

I'm working through the Meteor first app [tutorial](https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/creating-an-app) and cannot get the my app to run on an android phone or emulator. [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35778998/meteor-add-platform-error-with-android-home) my original question on Stack Overflow, which began as a request for help with unexpected `meteor add-platform android` errors and ended up being documentation of the adventure I've been on trying to fix it. The problem I'm having right now seems more suitable for Ask Ubuntu.

Right now, this is the issue I am having:

```
   sarah@sarah-ThinkPad-X220:~/simple-todos$ meteor add-platform --verbose android
Adding platform Android to Cordova project    
=> Errors executing Cordova commands:         

   While adding platform Android to Cordova project:
   Cordova error: CordovaError: Failed to fetch platform android
   Probably this is either a connection problem, or platform spec is incorrect.
   Check your connection and platform name/version/URL.
   undefined
   at
   /home/sarah/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.ki0ccv++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/platform.js:270:25
   at _rejected
   (/home/sarah/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.ki0ccv++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/q/q.js:797:24)
   at
   /home/sarah/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.ki0ccv++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/q/q.js:823:30
   at Promise.when
   (/home/sarah/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.ki0ccv++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/q/q.js:1035:31)
   at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch
   (/home/sarah/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.ki0ccv++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/q/q.js:741:41)
   at
   /home/sarah/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.ki0ccv++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/q/q.js:557:44
   at flush
   (/home/sarah/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.ki0ccv++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/q/q.js:108:17)
   at process._tickCallback (node.js:448:13)
   (If the error message contains suggestions for a fix, note that this may not apply to the Meteor integration. You can try
   running again with the --verbose option to help diagnose the issue.)
```

It seems to be a `cordova` issue that I am unsure how to fix. I tried clearing the Cordova cache, which changed nothing. I also attempted to reinstall `cordova`, which was successful, but gave these warnings:

```
sarah@sarah-ThinkPad-X220:~/simple-todos$ sudo npm install -g cordova
npm WARN engine deep-extend@0.4.1: wanted: {"node":">=0.12.0","iojs":">=1.0.0"} (current: {"node":"0.10.25","npm":"1.4.21"})
npm WARN deprecated npmconf@2.1.2: this package has been reintegrated into npm and is now out of date with respect to npm
npm WARN engine cordova-serve@1.0.0: wanted: {"node":">= 0.12.0","npm":">= 2.5.1"} (current: {"node":"0.10.25","npm":"1.4.21"})
npm WARN engine is-buffer@1.1.3: wanted: {"node":">=0.12"} (current: {"node":"0.10.25","npm":"1.4.21"})
/usr/local/bin/cordova -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/bin/cordova
cordova@6.0.0 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova
├── ansi@0.3.1
├── underscore@1.7.0
├── q@1.0.1
├── nopt@3.0.1 (abbrev@1.0.7)
├── update-notifier@0.5.0 (is-npm@1.0.0, string-length@1.0.1, repeating@1.1.3, semver-diff@2.1.0, chalk@1.1.1, configstore@1.4.0, latest-version@1.0.1)
└── cordova-lib@6.0.0 (valid-identifier@0.0.1, opener@1.4.1, properties-parser@0.2.3, shelljs@0.3.0, semver@4.3.6, nopt@3.0.6, dep-graph@1.1.0, npmconf@2.1.2, xcode@0.8.0, init-package-json@1.9.3, tar@1.0.2, request@2.47.0, cordova-app-hello-world@3.10.0, cordova-serve@1.0.0, aliasify@1.9.0, cordova-js@4.1.3, npm@2.15.1)
```

What should I try next?

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed this problem! I just had to remove the `npm_cache` dir.

```
$ sudo rm -r ~/.cordova/lib/npm_cache
```